# Get-LocalGroupMember generates error for Administrators group

Tags: windows-10, security-groups, local-groups

Following commands run on a Windows 10 VM that's joined to AzureAD:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators
>   Get-LocalGroupMember : Failed to compare two elements in the array. At
>   line:1 char:1
>
> PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Users
>   Group       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Unknown
>   Group       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE         Unknown
>
> PS C:\Windows\system32> net localgroup administrators
>   Members
>   Administrator AzureAD\UserName

Any idea why the PowerShell Get-LocalGroupMember command is generating an error on the Administrators group whereas net localgroup works as does Get-LocalGroupMember for the Users group?

Comment: Hrm, no repro on my win10 computers.

Comment: It works fine on my dev PC, just not this trial Windows 10 VM. Hmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been referenced as an official bug:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2996

Here is workaround:

http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/scripting/2342/query-local-administrators-with-cim/

UPDATE:

I had some issues with CIM and WMI.

Here is another workaround which worked everywhere for me.

https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/any-documented-adsi-changes-in-powershell-5-0/

Comment: Man, it's 8/23/2018 and this bug is still not fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by empty sids in the Administrators Group.
Open the Administrators group and remove the empty sids left behind from domain join/leave.
Before and After cleaning up the administrators group

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"
Get-LocalGroupMember : Failed to compare two elements in the array.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-LocalGroupMember], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An unspecified error occurred.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand
  ```

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"

ObjectClass Name                   PrincipalSource

---

User        MyMachine\Administrator Local
User        NA\otheradmin  AzureAD

you are welcome, working on a way cleaning up all empty sids from groups now.

Answer (score 0):

This will clean up the broken administrators. I think they were created during the update process:

(powershell script)

```
$administrators = @(
([ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators").psbase.Invoke('Members') |
% { 
 $_.GetType().InvokeMember('AdsPath','GetProperty',$null,$($_),$null) 
}
) -match '^WinNT';

$administrators = $administrators -replace "WinNT://",""

$administrators

foreach ($administrator in $administrators)
{

if ($administrator -like "$env:COMPUTERNAME/*" -or $administrator -like "AzureAd/*")
{
    continue;
}

Remove-LocalGroupMember -group "administrators" -member $administrator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the above script to remove empty SIDs and report anyone else.
Local users that are AzureAD Joined (onprem) using ADFS could be removed (set in azure ad / endpoint manager )

```
$administrators = @(
([ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators").psbase.Invoke('Members') |
% { 
 $_.GetType().InvokeMember('AdsPath','GetProperty',$null,$($_),$null) 
}
) -match '^WinNT';

$administrators = $administrators -replace "WinNT://",""

#$administrators

foreach ($administrator in $administrators)
{
#write-host $administrator "got here"
if ($administrator -like "$env:COMPUTERNAME/*" -or $administrator -like "AzureAd/*")
{
    continue;
}
elseif ($administrator -match "S-1") #checking for empty/orphaned SIDs only
{
write-host $administrator
Remove-LocalGroupMember -group "administrators" -member $administrator
}
write-host $administrator "check this users permissions if set in endpoint manager"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is empty SIDs in the Administrators Group caused by domain joins/leave/join etc.

Remove the empty sids and the command works just fine.